# Elastic Search 7 High level Client Create Index with mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

iam using elastic search 7.0.
I have a model which has to be saved to elastic.

When the index did not exist, then i try to save the documents directly to elastic:

```
final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("seminar_map", "seminar", id)
                    .source(new Gson().toJson(object), XContentType.JSON);
            indexRequest.id(id);
final IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Everything works fine and the documents will be saved to elastic.

But i want to have a custom analyzer and i need to change the mapping types.

So i tried to set up the index and the mapping before saving any documents with:

```
try {
            CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(index);
            request.settings(Settings.builder()
                    .loadFromSource(Strings.toString(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                            .startObject("analysis")
                            .startObject("analyzer")
                            .startObject("case_insensitive_analyzer")
                            .field("tokenizer", "keyword")
                            .field("type", "custom")
                            .field("filter", new String[]{"lowercase"})
                            .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                            .endObject()), XContentType.JSON)
            );

            XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
            builder.startObject();
            {
                builder.startObject("properties");
                {
                    builder.startObject("seminar_nummer");
                    {
                        builder.field("analyzer", "case_insensitive_analyzer");
                    }
                    builder.endObject();
                }
                builder.endObject();
            }
            builder.endObject();
            request.mapping("_doc",builder);

            return client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But i get the error:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true.]
```

How can i fix that error?

And is the plan correct to create a index and a mapping with not all parameter and then save the documents with more parameters than created.
So will elastic add the other missing parameters to the mappings or do i have to set the complete mapping within the creating index part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the `_doc` in the JSON you are creating and elastic complains about it because of [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

**Two options from here:**

1. Add `include_type_name=true` to the URL

OR

2. Replace this line `request.mapping("_doc",builder);` with `request.source(builder);`,

**See the docs for more details:**

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types (note the difference between 6.8 and 7.X)
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html#CO385-1

Comment: Hey,

- 1. Option: How can i add the paramter to the url using the `RestHighLevelClient`?  
- 2. Option: Changing to `request.source(builder)` throws the exception   `Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=unknown setting [index.properties.seminar_nummer.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings]`
Are there any changes within the hierachy of the parameters?

Comment: Regarding the url parameter: you need to go one abstraction level down and use the Low Level Rest Client.

Comment: Is your example still the same? Check if you provided a valid mapping type to the seminar_nummer field, for example  type: text. Have a look into the docs, how a valid mapping should look like and rebuild it using the client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html

Comment: The analyzer parameter should work.
Using postman its working to set the mapping of seminar_nummer to:
`"seminar_nummer": {
                    "type": "text",
     "analyzer": "case_insensitive_analyzer",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }`

And changing the parameter to **type : text** its the same exception

Comment: Not the analyser, you need a mapping type for each field/property definition under builder.startObject("seminar_nummer")

Comment: Changed to
`builder.startObject("properties");
                    {
                        builder.startObject("seminar_nummer");
                        {
                            builder.field("type", "text");
                        }
                        builder.endObject();
                    }
                    builder.endObject();`

same exception

Comment: Ok, as you are using the create index api, which supports setting and mappings, you need to nest the properties under "mappings" in order to distinguish the mappings from the settinng (you don't set, what's ok, as the defaults are applied)

Comment: Just to clarify the comment above: youn don't need to set settings, as long you don't need something different from the default index settings. Providing only a mapping is pretty fine.

Comment: Thanks. I used the lower rest client, to create the index with the mapping. Its the same like using postman. So thank you very much for the tip. It was not possible for me to use the RestHighLevelClient to create a index with a custom analyzer and a custom mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Types are deprecated in Elastic 7.x and will be removed in future versions of elastic. 
Changing `request.mapping("_doc",builder)` to `request.mapping(builder)` should work.

For the second question, Yes elastic search will add the missing fields that are not mentioned in the mapping when we save the documents.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
The problem is, that `request.mapping(builder)` is not working,, because the methods needs to have 2 parameters. 
`CreateIndexRequest mapping(String type, Object... source) {`

Comment: It has a method that takes only builder object. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.x/java-rest-high-create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

i also tried to seperate the create index with settings and the mapping part.
The create index + settings is working well.

But the step **add the mapping** are not working:

```
final PutMappingRequest requestMapping = new PutMappingRequest("seminar_map");

            XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
            builder.startObject();
            {
                    builder.startObject("properties");
                    {
                        builder.startObject("seminar_nummer");
                        {
                            builder.field("analyzer", "case_insensitive_analyzer");
                        }
                        builder.endObject();
                    }
                    builder.endObject();
            }
            builder.endObject();
            requestMapping.source(builder);

            client.indices().putMapping(requestMapping, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Dies gibt aber leider den Fehler:
`org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;`

But when iam adding a type to the request:
`requestMapping.type("_doc")`
it throws the exception

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true.]
```

So it doesnt work with a type and doesnt work without a type :-D